# Reload data in model every X minutes in Emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm building a component which takes as an input an IP and returns the error log of that computer. I have setup my model and adapter and they work, but I want to reload the data every few minutes to see if there is a new message.

My component is like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  init(){
    this.logMessages = this.get('store').query('log', {ip : this.attrs.ip.value});
    this._super(...arguments);
  },

  didLoad: function(){
    var self = this;
    Ember.run.later(function(){self.logMessages = self.get('store').query('log', {ip : self.attrs.ip.value}); console.log("reload");}, 3000);
  }
});
```

For some reason I never see the run.later actually running and no errors or warning show up either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to use a different lifecycle hook. As far as I know there is no didLoad, but you could use didRender, willRender, or didInsertElement based on your exact needs. I'd also remove the timer with one of the destroy hooks otherwise you'll leave timers running when the component is removed. Here is an outline of the lifecycle hooks:

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/

Comment: Ok, had to play a bit with the set and get values, but now works. Added it on the didRender and added a run.cancel on willDestroy. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly recommend using ember-concurrency (http://ember-concurrency.com/) for this. You can set a task that runs your `store` query periodically and have ember-concurrency handle the life-cycle hooks for you. Something like:

```
pollServerForChanges: task(function * () {
  while (true) {
    yield timeout(2000); // wait 2 seconds
    this.get('store').query(...)
  }
}).on('activate').cancelOn('deactivate').restartable(),
```

Comment: While your answer may be better, I have shipped the project and don't plan on revisiting it, at least for now. Also I am not sure I like the idea of having a library included in a project for a function that is only once or twice in a project.